# Decode an infrared signal with an IR demodulator inside a microphone jack

Tags: arduino, infrared, microphone, decoder

I was looking at [this tutorial](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/blog/eevblog-506-ir-remote-control-arduino-protocol-tutorial/) about how to decode an infrared signal.
One of the posts says

> For the scoped challenged (like me), a PC microphone jack works great
>   for reverse engineering IR protocol.  It even has power (5V through a
>   200-ohm resister, I think) to drive the IR transistor.  To see the
>   signal, use any audio recorder that lets you zoom in on the waveform
>   (like Audacity).

So I am just wondering if I can plug an IR demodulator (say, [this one here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001M1991W)) into my microphone jack, record the output, and decode the signal binary from the sound waves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can plug it in the microphone jack with a few extra components.

Here what schematic I have found on [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/)'s webpage (by [Matthias Ringwald](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/mringwal/lirc/)):

[image]

As far as I know most IR signals are Manchester coded:

- high to low transition means 1
- low to high transition means 0

Or the other way round because there are two [conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code#Conventions_for_representation_of_data).

Be sure to check [SB-Projects](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/index.php) for information regarding different IR protocols.

To view the signal on your PC I recommend [Christian Zeitnitz's Scope](http://www.zeitnitz.de/Christian/scope_en) and to record it try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net).

Comment: It may be worth noting that some IR receiver assemblies are *extremely* sensitive to power-supply noise.  What's drawn above as simply "+5" should probably--at minimum--have a bypass cap located very close to the receiver assembly.  I vaguely recall those decoders as often having open-collector rather than totem-pole outputs, in which case some form of pull-up might be necessary.  On the other hand, with some sound-card microphone inputs, eliminating the cap might eliminate the need for the pull-up [many microphone inputs include a weak current source to power electret mics].